# F# random class throws BadImageFormatException when calling .NextDouble()

Tags: random, f#, badimageformatexception

I have made a small application from a book about F#, but when I call the rand.NextDouble() method it throws a BadImageFormatException, which at first glance looks like it's something to do with images so I have NO idea what I'm supposed to do here.

I'm using VS community 2013 using visual F# 2013. I have 64 bit windows 7

I know it's the nextdouble method that's the problem through trying with a seperate let

```
let create_field num_asteroids =
    let lerp (x: float<'u>) (y:float<'u>) (a:float) =
        x*a+y*(1.0-a)

    let rand = Random()

    [for i =1 to num_asteroids do
        let m =
            (lerp earth_mass moon_mass (rand.NextDouble()))*
            1.0e-4
        let x = lerp 0.0<m> field_size (rand.NextDouble())
        let y = lerp 0.0<m> field_size (rand.NextDouble())
        let vx = max_velocity*(rand.NextDouble()*2.0-1.0)*0.1
        let vy = max_velocity*(rand.NextDouble()*2.0-1.0)*0.1
        yield
            {
            Position = { X = x; Y = y }
            Velocity = { X = vx; Y = vy }
            Mass = m
            Name = "a"
            }
    ]
```

This is the errorcode:

> System.BadImageFormatException was unhandled
>   Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in Asteroid_Field_1.exe
>   Additional information: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

MSDN tells me it might have something to with a DLL file not being loaded in the correct format, but I don't even know where to start.

http://pastebin.com/7LhCHr3c

this is the full code

I just tried it in FSI.exe and it works there just fine

Comment: How do you compile this and does it work in fsi?

Comment: it's a much bigger file so I don't want to copy pase it all. any suggestions?

Comment: I've linked a pastebin at the end

Comment: I am guessing the error is that your F# is not installed correctly.  Can you run a simple example in FSI to test if your F# is working properly?

Comment: Try to change which platform you compile against. Use the configuration manager to switch between `x86` and `x64`. `BadFormatException` is what you get when you try to load an assembly on the wrong architecture. From the code it looks game related, often graphics libraries have dependencies on architecture.

Comment: I've run a couple of console applications before and they all work, it's just the addition of the nextdouble method that makes it throw an exception.
I tried switching the CPU option to x86 but it doesnt change anything.

Comment: Does `rand.NextDouble()` work in fsi?

Comment: I want to be 100% clear, as your description is a bit indeterminate. So please verify : When you step through the visual studio debugger line by line starting a breakpoint, the rand.NextDouble() triggers the exception?

Comment: yes, but I "fixed" the problem by checking an option in the properties window.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by checking the "optimize code" in the properties of the project in visual studio. I got this fix from a fellow student.